# Is there a LaTeX package for units not included in siunits ?

Tags: units

I want to represent dBm in LaTeX. I have included the siunits package. But only dB is included. What is the best way to represent other units?

Comment: (1) Might be an idea to explain what dBm is, (2) It is explained in the manual how to define your own units or shortcuts to common unit combinations.

Comment: Is switching the package an option? Its easy to define your own units in the `siunitx` package  https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With `SIunits`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{SIunits}
\addunit\decibelm{dBm}
\begin{document}

\decibelm

\end{document}
```

I would (not surprisingly) use `siunitx`. This [looks like a separate unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm) for which I might use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\belmilliwatt}{Bm}
\DeclareSIUnit{\dBm}{\deci\belmilliwatt}
\begin{document}

\si{\deci\belmilliwatt}
\si{\dBm}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, if it's a qualifier then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{qualifier-mode = text}
\begin{document}

\si{\deci\bel\of{m}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thx Joseph! - one question: what do I need the  \si for? I have tried, it works with $\dBm$ as well.

Comment: @Luk In `siunitx` with the standard settings the unit macros are not globally defined, they are only available inside the arguments to `\si` and `\SI`. You can alter this if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

For `dBm` with `siunitx` ---

`\si{\dB\milli\nothing}`

This has an unwanted space between B and m, but it does not require declaring new units, so good for a quick implementation. [image: white space in dBm]

@daleif

> Might be an idea to explain what dBm is

dBm (or dBmW) means deci-bel milliwatt, or the power in milliwatts but written in 10*log10 format, e.g., 10 dBm = 10 mW.

It seems that [the author of `siunitx` refused to add this unit](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/166#issuecomment-17860775), since it is not a standard unit.

Well, it is an industrial (and academic) standard.